# Jquery ReferenceError: (function name) is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that got me stuck for days I don't understand why does it say in my console that my function is not defined here's the code. by the way, i am super new to jQuery I really don't have much knowledge in it so any help? can somebody tell me where I went wrong that it's giving me this error

> (ReferenceError: createGraph is not defined)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <script src="bin/js/raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="bin/js/popup.js"></script>
        <script src="bin/js/analytics.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="action-button">
    <button id="1" value="1074">Button 1</button>
    <button id="2" value="1074">Button 2</button>
 </div>

  <div id="output"></div>

<script>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// this script will check if the document is ready and will display data for button 1
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#1").trigger("click");
    });

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $("button").click(function () {
          var attr = $(this).attr("id");
          var val = $(this).val();

          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "bin/some.php",
          data: { lookbookID: val, type:attr  }
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#output").html(attr + ' - ' +  val + ' - ' + html );
        createGraph();

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS code

```
window.onload = function () {
    function getAnchors(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y) {
        var l1 = (p2x - p1x) / 2,
            l2 = (p3x - p2x) / 2,
            a = Math.atan((p2x - p1x) / Math.abs(p2y - p1y)),
            b = Math.atan((p3x - p2x) / Math.abs(p2y - p3y));
        a = p1y < p2y ? Math.PI - a : a;
        b = p3y < p2y ? Math.PI - b : b;
        var alpha = Math.PI / 2 - ((a + b) % (Math.PI * 2)) / 2,
            dx1 = l1 * Math.sin(alpha + a),
            dy1 = l1 * Math.cos(alpha + a),
            dx2 = l2 * Math.sin(alpha + b),
            dy2 = l2 * Math.cos(alpha + b);
        return {
            x1: p2x - dx1,
            y1: p2y + dy1,
            x2: p2x + dx2,
            y2: p2y + dy2
    };
}

    function createGraph() {
       // Grab the data
       alert("i made it!");
        var labels = [],
            data = [];
        $("#data tfoot th").each(function () {
        labels.push($(this).html());
        });
        $("#data tbody td").each(function () {
            data.push($(this).html());
        });

     }
    };
```

I updated this sorry I excluded that `window.onload` I still get that reference error but if I put the function outside `window.onload = function` then my function would work is there any way I can access my function? I don't know what will happen if I remove the said code from `windows.onload` I need help again :)

the link for the function just in case it would be of any help  https://github.com/ksylvest/raphael-analytics

Comment: That's not how functions are defined.  You need to learn basic Javascript syntax.

Comment: `$(function createGraph()() {` is a pretty blatant syntax error.

Comment: +1 Just fix the typo error.

Comment: thanks guys i didn't realize i had that $() lol epic fail anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function createGraph() {
// Grab the data
    var labels = [],
        data = [];
    $("#data tfoot th").each(function () {
        labels.push($(this).html());
    });
    $("#data tbody td").each(function () {
        data.push($(this).html());
    });

   //code here i erased so it wont be too long and i just added this function so i could call it anyway this code is actually the code that creates the graph in raphael JS
 }
```

Comment: You've got all kinds of dangling braces and parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks bro this one helped a lot

Comment: make a new question if it's not related to this specific problem

Comment: well it's the same i still get that reference error anyway i updated the JS above can you check if that's a good idea? thanks

Comment: try to wrap it in $(document).ready(function(){ // YOURCODE });

Comment: you mean the function createGraph() { } ?

Comment: It still says createGraph() is undefined ?

Answer (score 1):

createGraph is not a global function , Because $() create a new context,createGraph became a local variables,so if you try to call it ,you get an error.

so let it out from $().

Code like Upstairs..